# Create Email Notifications

Tags: orocommerce

I managed to create my own entity and a corresponding form in the backend, roughly following : https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities/crud/

Now I want to create a notification but
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/emails/#receive-email-notifications seems to be quite outdated (e.g. the Event.php class doesn't exist in the notification bundle) .
How would I do this in Oro 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this article is outdated.
Instead of

```php
$eventRepository = $manager->getRepository('Oro\Bundle\NotificationBundle\Entity\Event');
$event = $eventRepository->findOneByName('oro.notification.event.entity_post_persist');
$notification->setEvent($event);
```

you should call `setEventName` with the event name as a string argument:

```php
$notification->setEventName('oro.notification.event.entity_post_persist');
```

Thank you for the report. We'll update the documentation soon.